# Uid has already been taken in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm new in ruby on rails. I have done my deployment of ruby site (catarse) on linode. When I'm doing my first signup using normal method or aAuth i.e facebook login it creates the account. But when I'm trying to create another account I'm getting the error '**Uid has already been taken?**' Do anyone have idea about this error ? Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is an indication that you are trying to create a new user with a UID that already exists in the system. The best place to start is to look up the UID of your first created user - it's probably not what you expect it to be (perhaps nil, perhaps some error code). To fix, you'll want to find out what's causing your UID to be set incorrectly, and adjust that code in your user creation method.

Comment: I'm not a ruby developer. I just deployed ruby site on server. I found in the code but didn't succeed. I'm using postgreSql. Could it be a postgrSql validation which creates user with UNIQUE ID (Could be unique IP) ?